# Sudo with NOPASSWD and service restart

Tags: sudo, services

I have an `/etc/sudoers` with the following:

```
glens   ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/service php5-fpm
glens   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

And I'm trying to run the command:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/service php5-fpm restart
```

However, I'm still prompted for my password.

This [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246455/how-to-give-nopasswd-access-to-multiple-commands-via-sudoers) question/answer suggests I have the correct syntax, but I'm still prompted.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `NOPASSWD` entry should be placed beneath the other line:

```
glens   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL    
glens   ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/service php5-fpm
```

From the manual (`man sudoers`):

> When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order. 
>   Where there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not
>   necessarily the most specific match).

Therefore your order of `NOPASSWD` being first will be overridden by the second line (`ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`).

Comment: I see in the manpage that this is true, changing the order doesn't seem to have any effect on being prompted for a password.

Comment: You need a * at the end of the nopasswd sudoers entry to allow sudo to match 'restart'

Comment: Or the full command `glens   ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/service php5-fpm restart`