# How can I add lines into my sudoers file?

Tags: linux-mint, sudoedit

I have read this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/246430/332937) but don't know how to add the following line into my sudoers file.

```
matthew ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service fancontrol start
```

I ran "**sudo visudo**", and a "**/etc/sudoers.tmp**" window popped up. Is "**/etc/sudoers.tmp**" the correct file into which the line should be added? If so, under which line should I add the lines? How can I save it? I cannot find a "Save" option there. 
I aim to run "**sudo service fancontrol start**" without a password.

```
   GNU nano 2.9.3                   /etc/sudoers.tmp                             
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
```

Comment: Is this basically a question about how to use the `nano` editor? You can change editor by setting `VISUAL` and/or `EDITOR` to your preferred editor.

Comment: This is a question about how to add a line into my sudoers file, and Haxiel has answered my question. I even did not know "^G" denotes "Ctrl + G". I am a beginner in Linux.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`visudo` is a command provided for editing the sudoers file in a safe way. To quote [its manual page](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.17/visudo.man.html):

> visudo edits the sudoers file in a safe fashion, analogous to vipw(8).
>   visudo locks the sudoers file against multiple simultaneous edits,
>   provides basic sanity checks, and checks for parse errors.

The `/etc/sudoers.tmp` file is lock file used by `visudo`. Your changes are written to this temporary file so that `visudo` can carry out its checks. If everything checks out okay, the main `/etc/sudoers` file will be modified accordingly.

So when you run `sudo visudo`, a command line editor pops up so that you can edit the file. In your case, this editor appears to be GNU `nano`. In nano, you can navigate to the bottom of the file using arrow keys (or the <kbd>Page Down</kbd> key), and then paste the lines you want to include. Once your changes are done, you can exit the editor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and choose the 'Y' option to save the file (you'll be asked to confirm the filename - just hit Enter).

Your sudoers file should now be updated. You can use a pager like `less` to read the file and confirm that for yourself (the command to do that is `sudo less /etc/sudoers`).

Comment: Many thanks to Haxiel. Now I can start `Fancontrol` without a password. I don't understand what you mean by "use a pager like `less` to read the file"?  What is the command to bring up a pager like "less"?

Comment: @MatthewWai A "pager" is a program that shows you a text file, page by page, in a terminal.  `less` is a pager, as is `more`.  He means you can read the file by using `less /etc/sudoers` (as root).

Comment: Thanks! After pressing "**Enter**" as a response to "**File Name to Write: /etc/sudoers.tmp**", if "**visudo**" finds something wrong, what will happen? Will an error message be given?

Comment: @MatthewWai That's correct. In the manual page I have linked to, there is a section named 'DIAGNOSTICS' that shows the error messages that `visudo` will display, based on the problem encountered.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily add any line to sudoers by using:

```
echo 'whatever text you want to add' | sudo EDITOR='tee -a' visudo
```

In your case it would be:

```
echo 'matthew ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service fancontrol start' | sudo EDITOR='tee -a' visudo
```

Comment: But make sure you have a backup or alternate mechanism in case you mess up `sudoers`.

Answer (score 1):

## To use a different editor

`sudo EDITOR=«my_choice_of_editor» visudo`

Comment: I would pass EDITOR to sudo as an environment variable, not hope that it's allowed in the existing rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use vi or nano to edit `/etc/sudoers` file and you can also use `sudo visudo` to edit `/etc/sudoers` file.

After that, you can add your line with proper format.

```
## Next comes the main part: which users can run what software on
## which machines (the sudoers file can be shared between multiple
## systems).
## Syntax:
##
##      user    MACHINE=COMMANDS
##
## The COMMANDS section may have other options added to it.
##
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
YOUR_ENTRY ALL=(ALL)    ALL     ## enter here
```

Comment: `sudo visudo` is recommended.

Comment: It is the first time I have edited my sudoers file, and "sudo visudo" has done the job. I know nothing about "VISUAL and/or EDITOR", which Kusalananda mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command visudo -f /etc/sudoers add the content and save it